# Wpf update source trigger explicit on multiple textboxes when a button is clicked and command is executed. In MVVM scenario

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, updatesourcetrigger

I have a situation like this, I have a browse when I can double click an object and it opens in a form and then I am able to modify it (behind the scenes I am passing that object from one view model to another). Then I am able to modify its fields, however the textblock does it immediately, so I can see the fields changing before I press save changes, whats worse when I press cancel the modifications stay on the browse. 
I know I have to tell all the textboxes to UpdateSourceTrigger explicit, but I cannot find a simple example in an MVVM way, so only update when the button save is clicked and command associated with it is executed, that should force that explicit update on all texboxes. Any ideas how can I achieve it?

Thanks :)

Comment: You use magic.  Or, you send a *copy* of the model, then wait for an OK, and on OK copy the values back to the original.  Then you do a little dance and drink a little water.

Comment: Thanks I did something similar to what you say and it seems to work. So I pass the object, and then on the form i make a copy of it, but creating new object and then getting all the properties from the original one, and then the user may only change the coppy. If save is pressed the coppy is send back to the browse and replaces the original object, if cancel is pressed then nothing happens, the form just goes back to the browse, and the copy is just simply left behind, as it was changed but never saved. Now I can have that little dance, or try to solve another problem :P

Comment: Okay, since that was so simple, I'll move my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use magic. Or, you send a copy of the model, then wait for an OK, and on OK copy the values back to the original. Then you do a little dance and drink a little water.